# How to connect to a beacon ESTIMOTE

Tags: ios, objective-c, estimote

I am looking at the SDK for iPhone for estimate beacons, I see

```
- (void)connectToBeacon
```

to connect to the beacon, but how can i pass it is UUID,Major and Minor to connect, doesn't seem to allow me.

any advice would be great..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the major/minor when connecting to a beacon. This method is used to connect to a beacon in order to change things like the UUID, major, and minor broadcast values. This would be used like:

```
ESTBeacon *myBeacon = ...;
[myBeacon connectToBeacon];
```

Edit: you need to connect to a Beacon in range, and you can typically get that beacon from `ESTBeaconManager`'s `beaconManager:didDiscoverBeacons:inRegion:` which will give you a `NSArray` of `ESTBeacon` objects in range.

Comment: No worries stonz2 I have got it :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
// you declare your beacon and your manager
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTBeacon* myBeacon;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ESTBeaconManager* beaconManager;

// You create the objects 
self.beaconManager = [[ESTBeaconManager alloc] init];
myRegion = [[ESTBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID
                                                      major:11111 minor:22222 identifier:@"beacon1"];
// this will returns an array of beacons
- (void)startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)myRegion

// this will allow  you to manage the array.
-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
     didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
            inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)myRegion
```